# Return Fiscal Month based on today's date (or) VLOOKUP return contents of merged cell

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I have a workbook that pulls data dynamically based on a date range (C1=*startdate*, D1=*enddate*). When a user enters the workbook, Excel needs to check TODAY() and then populate the startdate in C1 with the first day in that FISCAL month (which can be any number day of the month). So if a user enters the workbook on 2 May, 2014, it should populate the *startdate* in C1 as 4/30/2014 (that's when the fiscal month begins).

I have the fiscal dates set up in a separate worksheet for reference (if needed- see pic). In my example, I am not sure how to return 4/30/2014 if TODAY() = 2 May 2014 (in the pic, the red square is 1 May) from the grid-style I have on the left. I tried setting up a more traditional table on the right and using a VLOOKUP, but when Excel finds 5/2/2014 in Column N, it reads the column next to it as 0, instead of returning the value for that entire merged cell.

[image]

Comment: I have unmerged the cells on the right and then dragged the dates down across the same region for each month that was previously merged. This works, but there's gotta be a better way I would think.

Comment: have you looked at the workday() function?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you use financial weeks as we do at the company I work for in the UK, you can have a reference table created in the below image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZPpr.jpg

Which generates the below (fiscal months and quarters added manually). Column A uses WeekNum to change each fiscal week start date to a calendar week number. C2 is manually set as the first day of the fiscal year.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDKf4.jpg

From here you can use the formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(WEEKNUM(TODAY(),1),A:F,2,FALSE)
```

To return the column for fiscal week or month. If you want fiscal month start, you can add this as a column, or use the below to generate it from month number and year start.

```
"Year Start"+(28*("Month Number"-1))
```

**UPDATE:**

If you calculate the difference between your fiscal week number and calendar week number, you could adjust your WeekNum result to should Fiscal Week. This would reduce the logic needed in the table.